# How to detect non-intrusive phone call

Tags: ios, swift, ios14

In iOS 14 you can now accept phone calls that do not take up the entire screen (the new non-intrusive phone call UI looks like a push notification). If you accept the call, but do not open up the full screen call UI, the app remains open. This is true even if you pick up the phone and put it to your ear the app remains active.

What would the best way be to detect an incoming call, or that the user began the call?

Answer (score 2):

You can’t detect it. If the user just takes the call direct from the banner, your app remains active and there is nothing to detect. That is the whole point of this feature: a call need not interrupt your app in any way.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Shouldn't there be a notification fired when the user brings the phone up to their ear to answer the call? Why does the app remain active still at that point?